# YII form builder render view is not working

Tags: yii, yii2

[image: in my network tab]

The extension used; https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/formbuilder#examples

My code

```
<?php    
/* @var $this yii\web\View */    
use meysampg\formbuilder\FormBuilder;    
?>

<?= FormBuilder::widget([
    'showActionButtons' => 'true',
    'dataType' => 'json',
    'elementType'=> 'div',
    'accessVariableName' => 'formBuilderJsVariable',
    'messages' => [
        "autocomplete" => "Autocomplete 23",
    ],    
]); ?>
```

when I click save button. form view is not showing please help

Comment: Do you get any error, including browser console?  What the **Network** tab in chrome after clicking shows?

Comment: i upload a image of network tab can u help me please....

Comment: check console of browser to maybe you have js error

Comment: there is no errors in  console. is that extension have view page or we have to design it ? i didn't use any code to view  page.any tutorials please